# How to get element by attribute with Selenium, Xpath and Expected Condition

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

This is what I'm using:

```
getByAttribute = WebDriverWait(amazonDriver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@an-attribute='data-category']")))
```

The element looks as follows:

```
<div class='nav-subnav' data-category='drugstore'>
```

This is present on every Amazon products page.

It times out and does not find the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@data-category` to get element by attribute.

```
getByAttribute = WebDriverWait(amazonDriver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-category]")))
```

CSS Selector:

```
getByAttribute = WebDriverWait(amazonDriver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-category]")))
```